# How can I scroll in droid@screen?

Tags: android, android-scroll

I am using Droid@Screen tool for screen-casting my Android app.  I am not able to scroll the screen in Droid@screen.  What are other alternatives to Droid@Screen?  Are there any workarounds for this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Use [Vysor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vysor/gidgenkbbabolejbgbpnhbimgjbffefm) . Couldn't scroll with droid@screen but Vysor worked great. You can also use the mouse wheel or keyboard arrows to scroll there.